# Git add . ignores .gitignore

Tags: git

```
$ git --version:  
git version 1.7.9.5

$ cat /etc/issue:  
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l

$cat .gitignore  
**/._*  
**/*.swp  
**/.DS_Store  
log/  
bak/  

$ git status  
On branch master  
Changes not staged for commit:  
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)  
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)  

modified:   html/conf/._conf.php  
modified:   html/conf/conf.php  

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

As shown above, i included **/._* in my .gitignore.
I created the .gitignore first, then "git init" and finaly "git add .". I commited everything and then changed html/conf/conf.php. As you can see in the output of "git status" the ._conf.php is not ignored. Anyone here, who can help me with that? I read so many tutorials, but obviously i'm missing something.

Does "git add ." ignore the ignore-list? If so, what do i have to do to avoid that? New created files matching **/._* are ignored correctly.

Trying "git update-index --assume-unchanged **/._*" results in
fatal: Unable to mark file doku/._blabla.txt

I'm running out of ideas ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think `**/` is accepted shell glob syntax for subdirectories. As far as git goes, anyway. If you want to ignore dotfiles, just don't provide a path: `.*`

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` is taking into consideration only for new files.

If your files are already tracked by Git and then modified the changes should be staged with `git add .`.

You can set the status of these files to "assume unchanged" with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html